# Disable certain key's default action

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard

```
function keypressCheck() {
    var keyID = event.keyCode;

    //space pressed
    if (keyID == 32) {
        anotherFunction();
    }
}
```

I want `anotherFunction()` to run when the space bar is pressed without the default action of the page scrolling to happen. is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should work. Just to make sure, try this:

```
function keypressCheck(e) { 
    var e = window.event||e; // Handle browser compatibility
    var keyID = e.keyCode;
    //space pressed
    if (keyID == 32) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action
        anotherFunction();
    }
}
```