# as3 AIR Win- preventing ALT+spacebar in fullscreen windows

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, addeventlistener

I have a local fullscreen AIR app (that loads several SWFs from a server),
and I'm trying to use `ALT+<letter>` as shortcuts.

But Windows OS intercepts the `ALT` key, and for example displays upper-left-corner-windows-menu when I press `ALT+Space`, which I want to prevent.

I found these posts, that seemed to be a solution:

- http://blog.six4rty.ch/2010/11/09/air-quick-hint-suppress-keyboard-events/
- http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2009/12/adobe-air-preventing-users-from-closing-the-app/
- [Disable certain key's default action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987406/disable-certain-keys-default-action)

But no luck.
I've tried to use `preventDefault()` like this:

```
this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, ff);
...
function ff(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
```

But this doesn't prevent the OS from intercepting the `ALT` key...

Some clue about what is lacking?

/thanks
/j

I'm compiling in Flash CS5.5 / Win XP / Air 2.6 
There's no difference if I compile and run the Air-app, or just debug from the Flash IDE (`Ctrl+Enter`).

Answer (score -1):

you can't prevent that, because it is an OS function. it's like you're trying to prevent ctrl+alt+del, its not allowed. 
With AS3 preventDefault, you only prevent the virtual machine's events, the OS 'bubbling' continues. You wouldn't have luck with ANE as well, because you can't do this in c++ either.

Comment: csmoakk, thank you for your answer!
The real issue is not really to prevent `CTRL+ALT+DEL` nor `ALT+space` which I can live without. The trouble is that the `ALT`key has some strange behavior when you press it and then release it. If you release it, then the next key isn't detected...

I suppose I'll have to use some other key combination, but this one seemed to be the right one for the task... if nobody else has some opinion?

Comment: alt does not count as a regular key. its a parameter on the keyboard event. so if you press alt, no event gets fired. if you press 'h' for example, while holding alt, keycode will be 'h'-s, and altPresset will be true. Alt however can open your browsers menu, what means Flash player losing focus, so the keys hit after that will not fire events, until you click the Flash again. Defending against it can be with fullscreeninteractive mode.

Comment: csmoakk, is this still true in AIR? As i put in the question, it's a fullscreen AIR app...
And in this case, ALT **does** trigger a KeyboardEvent, with a keycode=18.
If I press `ALT+A` I get two keyboard events triggered: first with keycode=18, and then one with keycode=65.
I can check for the `A` and test if event.altKey is true. That is not the problem...
The issue is still that if I press **and release** `ALT` then the next key is not dispatching any event.