# Disable keys in html number input

Tags: html, input

I have a webapp build with HTML5 and jQuery Mobile.
With the following HTML element I will get a text field in which I only can input numbers:

```
<form>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="numfield">Input:</label>
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="numfield" id="numfield" value="" />
</div>
</form>
```

If I tap the text field, the virtual keyboard of the mobile phone or the tablet appears. The keyboard allows the input of numbers 0-9. This is what I was expected.
Now I want to allow only the numbers 1-4 to insert. The length can vary so it should be possible to input for example the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, ...
I know that I can catch the keypress event to check the tapped buttons but I want to inform the user that only some keys are accessible already when the keyboard is displayed (layout reason).
So my question: Is it possible to disable buttons on this keyboard? Changing the pattern attribute to [1-4]* has no effect.

Comment: This is answered hundreds of times on the internet, please search.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987406/disable-certain-keys-default-action

Comment: See input type: number on: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp you can specify a min and a max.

Comment: With the min and max attributes I can only define a range. But I don't know the smallest and the biggest number previously and what about gaps? Let's say I want to allow the input of numbers 1-5 with a maxlength of 4 so I define min=1 and max=5555. But that doesn't work beacause in this case the numbers 100 or 999 for example are also possible and that's an error.

@Seano666: I know I can handle the keypress event but that only prevents the change of the content. The keys on the virtual keyboard are still enabled.

Comment: What's the difference between the key being disabled and it not doing anything when you press it?  If you are talking about virtual keyboards then you still may have the 'press' animation, but is that it?  Would help if we knew what kind of application or had some code to look at.  You might even get someone who knows what they're doing instead of me. ;)

Comment: From your comments, it seems that you really want to control the virtual keyboard that appears (in some situations). You should edit the question accordingly – it now seems to ask about disabling the effects of physical keys (which is possible, though not with HTML).

Comment: The short answer is unfortunately No. The keyboards on all devices I've worked with do not allow customisation in this way. Sucks doesn't it.