# datepicker loses focus when enter key hit on readonly input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have searched this site and apparently my issue is somewhat unique.  I have made two input boxes readonly:

```
$(rowSelected.childNodes[0].childNodes[1]).prop('readonly', true);
$(rowSelected.childNodes[1].childNodes[1]).prop('readonly', true);
```

and then I disable enter key and backspace key on keyboard for these inputs:

```
$(rowSelected.childNodes[0].childNodes[1]).keydown(function(event){
     if(event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 8){
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
      }
   })
```

Same code is used for second input box.  This code disables the backspace key but when I hit enter the datepicker goes away.  How can I stop default behaviour for enter key on these inputs.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable certain key's default action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987406/disable-certain-keys-default-action)

Comment: @thomas tried this with same result.  enter key still causes datepicker to disappear.