# Prevent line break on textarea when Shift + Enter is pressed

Tags: javascript

How to disable line breaks on the `<textarea>` when `shift + enter` is pressed.

The attached code here below disables line break when only `enter` is pressed. I want to disable `shift + enter` as well.

```
onKeyPress={(event) => {
   if (event.key === 'Enter' && !event.shiftKey) {
      onInputPressEnter(event, elementsRefs);
      setSubmitted(true);
   }
}}
```

Comment: @PeterB the above link answers how to detect and *enable* "shift+enter", this question instead wants to ***disable*** "shift+enter"

Comment: I wrote an answer. I hope it will help.

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987406/disable-certain-keys-default-action

Comment: Please show us the code which actually disables `enter`

Comment: I edited it now maybe now it will help

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake it should be `(event .... })`.

You wrote: `{(event) .... }}`

So I added `tarea` because the Code has to know which texture you mean then I removed`!` from `if` statement.

corrected code:

```
    const tarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
    tarea.onKeyPress=(event => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter' || (event.key === 'Enter' && event.shiftKey)) {
       event.preventDefault();
       onInputPressEnter(event, elementsRefs);
       setSubmitted(true);
    }
})
```

Comment: Considering the actual disabling code isn't provided in the question this answer doesn't help anyone expect the asker.

Comment: Maybe it helps now?